# Hide scrollbar during transition in Angular Animation

Tags: angular, scrollbar, transition, angular-animations

I need help on hiding scrollbar during transition .

```
    trigger("routeFadeState", [
  transition(":enter", [
    style({
      transform: "translateY(-100vh)"
    }),
    animate("1000ms ease-out")
  ]),
  transition(":leave",
    animate(
      "500ms",
      style({
        transform: "translateY(-100vh)",
        overflow: hidden
      })
    )
  )
]);
```

I'm trying to implement slideInfromTop on :enter and slideOutToTop on :leave . The screen which slideIn should occupy the full screen height and full screen width .

During :enter , my code works perfect . the screen smoothly slidesin with neither vertical scrollbar nor horizontal scrollbar . Scrollbars don't appear at all .

During :leave , though the screen slides out , I see scrollbars appear for a split-second . I want to get rid of that .

I don't use any css frameworks .

Please help me out

[image]

Comment: can you put up a minimal working example in stackblitz

Comment: Hey @joyBlanks . Please refer this 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1jpxga?embed=1&file=src/index.html
On Clicking on lorem ipsum text , you will see the about component kickin . I want to get rid of the scrollbars

Comment: check your answer. Please mark it if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many items which lead to the scrollbars.

- The html body defaults to some margin and padding lose them first in your global CSS

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

- In your global styles I added the `position:absolute` part to all component that will be loaded in the **<router-outlet>** so all component will be positioned absolutely so you don't have to go to each component and write `position: absolute`, `display: block`, `width` and `height`. Your styles for your global css for your routed component as follows

```
router-outlet + * {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

- Update your component CSS (Optional). So now your components CSS become simple:

```
Home (CSS)                      |  About (CSS)
:host {                         |  :host { 
  background-color: yellow;     |    background-color: red;
}                               |  }
```

- Last thing the notorious one: Lose the **<p>** tags or lose their margins (always bangs my head good) use **<div>** tags. They impact the overall page margin somehow.

---

Updated Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdxphn

Now you have a much cleaner base and route animations will never trouble you again.

Cheers✌